# Send CryptoJS AES var over Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, encryption, socket.io, aes, cryptojs

I'm writing a socket.io app, and I have a variable, `aesMsg`, which I want to send to the server. `aesMsg` is encrypted with CryptoJS, like so:

`var aesMsg = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(emsg, "key");
//emsg is the plaintext variable I'm encrypting. It is a string.`

I then try to send this variable to my Node.js socket.io server, like so:

`socket.emit("chat message", aesMsg, xname);
//xname doesn't have anything to do with the encryption.`

When I try to `emit` the socket.io event containing `aesMsg`, it fails silently and I haven't been able to figure out why. I can't convert the variable to a string, as it needs to remain in its current form for decryption on the other end to work properly.

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot debug your code for you from here. Try without encryption, check for server logs, etc.

Comment: Why to encrypt the message at all? Aren't you using HTTPS?